# Ruby: Compare Instances of Class to each Other

Tags: ruby, comparison-operators

I have a test which relies on comparing instances of the same class to each other.

```
d022 = SimpleDate.new(2016, 1, 1)
d023 = SimpleDate.new(2016, 1, 1)
d024 = SimpleDate.new(2016, 1, 2)

assert(d022 == d022)
assert(d022 == d023)
refute(d024 == d022)
```

My class functions are able to pass the first two tests but not the last one.  What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
class SimpleDate
  attr_reader :year, :month, :day

  def initialize(year, month, day) 
    @year = year
    @month = month
    @day = day
  end

  def ==(val)
    @year == @year && @month == @month && @day == @day
  end

  def !=(val)
    @year != @year || @month !=@month || @day != @day
  end
end
```

Comment: You just have to implement `==`, not-equal is provided by [`BasicObject#!=`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/BasicObject.html#method-i-21-3D).

Comment: Or include [Comparable](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.2/Comparable.html) and define a <=> method

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong in my code?

You're comparing values to themselves. This doesn't look suspicious to you?

```
  def ==(val)
    @year == @year && @month == @month && @day == @day
  end
```

Hint: you're not using `val` in any way here.

Comment: yes that makes sense.  I'm still getting issues and will post again.

Answer (score 1):

You should be comparing the current object's attributes with the attributes of `val` passed in

```
class SimpleDate
  attr_reader :year, :month, :day

  def initialize(year, month, day) 
    @year = year
    @month = month
    @day = day
  end

  def ==(val)
    @year == val.year && @month == val.month && @day == val.day
  end

  def !=(val)
    @year != val.year || @month != val.month || @day != val.day
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you iGbanam.  I am still getting issues and will post again.

Comment: How do I handle using <=> ?   The below doesn't work:                            def <=>(val)
    @year <=> val.year && (at)month <=> val.month && (at)day <=> val.day
  end

Comment: @iGbanam answer looks good. Is there something else that you are doing? Maybe use a debug or console log to check.

Comment: You could drop this into IRB and verify it works. I don't think I tested this when I wrote it — can't remember really. But it looks like it should work 